# In-app autorenewable subscriptions walk-thru

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

I'm tearing my hair out trying to work out the work-flow for auto-renewable subscriptions on iOS. It's not even clear whether I require a server to do this. I just have one product - a monthly subscription. What are the steps to getting this working? Is there a walk-thru anywhere?

Comment: have you read https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. If you're app is not a periodical like a magazine, then you should steer away from ARS (auto-renewable subscriptions). Apple may reject it and insist you use NRS (non-renewing subscriptions).

To answer your question, my two best resources were [Apple's Verifying In-App Purchase Receipts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW2) and this guide on [Verifying Receipts from your server using PHP and cURL](http://phpriot.com/articles/verifying-app-store-receipts-php-curl).

Basically, if you're using NRS you'll need your own server.  But if you're doing ARS which is what you asked about, you don't *have* to use your own server.  It's just recommended for better security.  If you don't use your own server and you do the verifications straight from the app, you have to include your `shared secret` in the app which could get sniffed out.  Also, you're more likely to be vulnerable to someone hacking the network communication to trick your app into thinking the user purchased a subscription.

Comment: auto renewable subscriptions seems to be working not only for newsstand apps

Comment: @raistlin That wouldn't surprise me. The point I'm making though is that Apple is very selective about which apps they allow to use ARS. I haven't yet heard any evidence to the contrary.